# ASP.NET MVC Reject On Additional Fields

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

In ASP.NET MVC, I have HTTP method

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SampleMethod(LoginModel prmModel)
{

}
```

And LoginModel is like:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I want the request **to fail**, if the request body has **more fields** than expected (Username and Password)

If HTTP Request Body is **`{Username: 'U', Password: 'P', Dummy:'D' }`** the request should fail because of 'Dummy' field in my case. (Exception or Bad Request response)

How can I restrict MVC Model Binder to behave this way on certain methods only?
This requirement is not for all methods, for certain models in project.

Comment: If someone post `{Username: 'U', Password: 'P', Dummy:'D' }` then ASP.NET MVC model binding will automatically skip `Dummy` and bind only UserName and Password to `LoginModel` model. Then what is your concern?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The default model binder, would ignore the Dummy property anyway.

Comment: I do NOT want to ignore and continue with bindable fields. I want MVC to generate error and fail if non-expected fields encountered in body.

Comment: you can check `Request.Form["Username "]` and Request.Form["Password"] in your controller actions if other than this form key found then you can throw exception and handle it like `Request.Form["Dummy"]`  then throw exception

Comment: @LaljiDhameliya Of course I can do this but I am searching for built-in generic approaches.

Comment: you can check your model properties name `prmModel.GetType().GetProperties().Select(x=>x.Name)` and check this list into `Request.Form` of key value is exist other than this or not

Comment: @AhmetAltun - There is no built in approach because nobody cares about this, other than you apparently.

Comment: It can be done using Model Binder and Newtonsoft.JSON library, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55626307/asp-net-mvc-reject-on-additional-fields/55631785#answer-55631785)

Answer (score 1):

If you can use [Newtonsoft.JSON](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) library, there is [MissingMemberHandling property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeMissingMemberHandling.htm) in `JsonSerializerSettings`. You can write custom model binder to deserialize an object from json using this property, like this:

```cs
public class StrictJsonBodyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(string))
        {
            if (bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType != "application/json")
            {
                throw new Exception("invalid content type, application/json is expected");
            }

            using (var bodyStreamReader = new StreamReader(bindingContext.HttpContext.Request.Body))
            {
                var jsonBody = await bodyStreamReader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
                var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Error,
                };
                var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonBody, bindingContext.ModelType, jsonSerializerSettings);
                bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(model);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could use this model binder with `ModelBinderAttribute` for specific action argument:

```cs
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SampleMethod([ModelBinder(typeof(StrictJsonBodyModelBinder))] LoginModel prmModel)
{
}
```

Now, when invalid properties will be passed, `JsonConvert` will throw error (will be HTTP 500 for users if error will not be handled).

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult SampleMethod()
{
    dynamic prmModel= System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode((new StreamReader(Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd()));

    Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JsonSchema schema = JsonSchema.Parse(Jsonschema());
    Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject user = JObject.Parse(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(prmModel));
    if (!user.IsValid(schema) || user.Count > 2)
        return Json("Bad Request");
}

public string Jsonschema()
{
    string schemaJson = @"{
        'description': 'A',
        'type': 'object',
        'properties': {
            'UserName':{'type':'string'},
            'Password':{'type':'string'}
            }
        }";

    return schemaJson;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to implement this requirement is check `Request.Form.Keys.Count != 2 or > 2`

```
        if (Request.Form.Keys.Count > 2)
        {
            return View("Error"); // handle error
        }
        else
        {
            // handle logic here
        }
```

Comment: It should be `Request.Form.Keys.Count>3` because there is a hidden `AntiForegeryToken` field